# Is there an automatic release with setTitle (UIButton class)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, retain

As everyone knows, setTitle automatically retains the string passed as a parameter. When the button caption needs to be changed, I guess that it is necesary to release the current (old) string before setting the new one. I wonder what is the most elegant way to dot it.

See my code sample (here, getPlayerHandFromGame method produces autoreleased strings which are retained when setTitle is invoked):

```
colourString = [pGame getPlayerHandFromGame:1 withColour:COLOUR_HEARTS];


// Split colourString into array of strings if not null.
    if ([colourString length] != 0) {
        listCards = [colourString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        for (cardCounterSameColour = 1; cardCounterSameColour <= [listCards count]; cardCounterSameColour ++) {
            currentCardButton = [self buttonCardNumber:cardCounter];
            // Objects are numbered from 0 in the array
            [currentCardButton setTitle:[listCards objectAtIndex:cardCounterSameColour-1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            cardCounter ++;
        }
    }
```

This portion of code will be called several times since the button caption will be updated several times. I guess that before setting the title, I should do something like this:

```
[currentCardButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal release]
```

in order to release the string which will not be used anymore (titleForState returns a pointer to the NSString).

Is that the right way to avoid that the device memory gets loaded with unused strings ?

Many thanks,
Apple92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As everyone knows, setTitle automatically retains the string passed as a parameter.

Really?  I don't know it.  In fact, I'll bet a pint of beer that it doesn't retain the string, but copies it.

Granted, for an NSString, -copy is probably implemented as doing a retain and returning self, but if you pass it an NSMutableString, a genuine copy will occur.

> I guess that it is necesary to release the current (old) string before setting the new one.

Guess again, sucker!

Or less facetiously: any object is responsible for managing the ownership of other objects it wantsa to keep hold of.  Once you have passed the title in setTitle: you do not need to worry about how the object disposes of it once it gets a new one.

Consider the code:

```
[currentCardButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

and apply the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) to the return result.

Did you obtain it with alloc, new or copy?  No.  Did you retain it?  No (remember we are talking about the object passed back by the method,*not* the object you originally gave it).  Therefore, you *must not* release it.

Answer (score 6):

Any class that retains a value set on one of its properties is also responsible for releasing the old value when that property's value gets changed again. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the object ownership convention:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB

Every class should follow these rules (Apple's does it), so in order to them you dont have to worry because you haven't done a alloc/retain in your class, and the button will retain it for it's internal use.